# Problems with YamlConfiguration.set()

Tags: java, bukkit

Hey there,

I've got a small problem. I am creating a plugin for [Bukkit](http://dev.bukkit.org/). I tried to code a in-game config editor - that means that one can change configuration options with a command from inside the game. I already got it to work, but as of the build I'm using (#2879), the method `YamlConfiguration.set(String, Object)` doesn't seem to work. Here is the essential part of my code for setting and saving the [`YamlConfiguration`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/file/YamlConfiguration.html) I've got.

```java
plugin.debug("option = "+option); // the configuration option
plugin.debug("newvalue = "+value); // the new value
config.set(option, value); // this should set the value of 'option' to 'value'
plugin.debug("savedvalue = "+config.get(option)); // the value saved in the config
```

As I tested my plugin, I've got the following output.

```java
option = debug
newvalue = false
savedvalue = true
```

If you need the full and detailed code, look into it on GitHub: [GeneralCommands.java](https://github.com/lirtistasya/RegionManager/blob/master/src/com/lirtistasya/bukkit/regionmanager/commands/GeneralCommands.java), function `config(CommandSender, String, String)` (line 1074).

Kind regards.

Comment: Making a debug method is smart. I don't know why I never thought to make one.

Comment: The method set() only works if the YamlConfiguration has the option already in it. I think you need to do addDefault(option, value) at least once before you can do set(option, value). I'm not exactly sure though, so try it and report back if it works.

Comment: @InspiredOne Hm, that might be a possibility. I'll try it. But I have to say that everytime before this error, I never ever used `addDefault()` before and it still worked (see [ConfigProperties.java](https://github.com/lirtistasya/RegionManager/blob/master/src/com/lirtistasya/bukkit/regionmanager/configuration/ConfigProperties.java))

Comment: @InspiredOne Well, it didn't work out. I am not using a complete new `YamlConfiguration`, I get it via `plugin.getConfig()` (which I coded myself; see GitHub).

Comment: Oh, okay. It was not a problem with the `set()` method but with the `plugin.getConfig()` method. My bad.

By the way, how can I tag a question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was a problem with another method I used (`plugin.getConfig()`).